# Using scalar variable or a pointer to print 2D array

Tags: c, linux, pointers, echo, scalar

How do I use a **scalar variable or a pointer** to print 2D string array? The program needs to execute the system command “echo” to print out all the strings

Input:

```
char myarray[2][10] = {"Hello", "World"};
for (j=0;j<2;j++){    
    setenv ("myvar", myarray[j]);
    system("echo $myvar");       
}
```

Actual Output:

```
Hello
World
```

Expected Output:

```
Hello World
```

Comment: A pointer is a form of scalar type. Arithmetic types and pointer types = scalar types. Arrays and struct/union = aggregate types. But these terms aren't used much outside the C standard.

Comment: @plasmacel Umm... no? The term aggregate is there in C even in the [draft for C90](http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt), from 1988, see 3.1.2.5. There is nothing called "POD" in the C standard.

Comment: @Lundin Well, it's good to know.

Answer (score 3):

You see that your problem can be solved by simply avoiding new line character in echo. By using `man` command on `echo` (`man echo`) we can see

> -n     do not output the trailing newline

So we can do this by replacing

```
system("echo $myvar");
```

by

```
system("echo -n $myvar");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-ne`

```
system("echo -ne $myvar");
```

Will leave the cursor at the start of the line containing the `Hello`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the exact solution. However I am still not using pointer/scalar variable.

```
char myarray[2][10] = {"Hello", "World"};

for (j=0;j<2;j++){    
setenv ("myvar", myarray[j]);
system("echo -n $myvar' '");      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I use a scalar variable or a pointer to print 2D string array

Arrays under certain condition decay to a pointer to their 1st element. One of those case is when they get assigned (to the right pointer variable).

```
char myarray[2][10] = {"Hello", "World"};
```

is a an array of array of `char`. So `myarray[0]` is an array of `char[10]`. A `char[10]`'s 1st element is a `char`.

You can do

```
char * p = myarray[0];
```

Then `p` points to `myarray[0]`'s 1st element. It points to `myarray[0][0]`. `p` gets the address of `myarray[0][0]` assigned.

Following this you can modify your code like this:

```
for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {    
  char p = myarray[j];
  setenv ("myvar", p);
  system("echo $myvar");       
}
```

The code uses `p` to print.

Still there a easier ways to print in C:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* for printf() */

...

for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
  char p = myarray[j];
  printf("%s", p);
}
```